# How do i replace something but also keep it? Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, notepad, programmers-notepad

```
Document1:Document2
Document3:Document4
Document5:Document6
Document20:Document21
Document22:Document23
Document24:Document25
```

So, i wanna split from the sixth document so it would look like this,

```
Document1:Document2
Document3:Document4
Document5:Document6

Document20:Document21
Document22:Document23
Document24:Document25
```

But, how can i \n without deleting this? "Document5:Document6"

Comment: Include it in the replace string.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Find: "Document5:Document6" Replace with: "Document5:Document6\n"

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Document5:Document6`
- Replace with: `$0\n` or `$0\r\n` depending on your needs
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Document5:Document6     : literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          : The whole match (i.e. Document5:Document6)
\n          : line feed
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Document1:Document2
Document3:Document4
Document5:Document6

Document20:Document21
Document22:Document23
Document24:Document25
```